# conditionally adding css class using renderer in md-table md-row is not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, nodes, angular-material2

I am trying to add css class in `md-row` of `md-table` using Renderer but it never got applied.

Here is my code.

```js
constructor( private renderer: Renderer ) { }

onContextMenuClick(e: Event){
 // do something...
 // add css class based on condition
 this.renderer.setElementClass(e.currentTarget, 'selected', true);
  
  
}

<md-row  *cdkRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" 
  [ngClass]="uniqueRow(row.id)" // To update/remove row by the unique Id
         (contextmenu)="onContextMenuClick($event,row.id)" // Do something on contextmenu click
         [class.checkbox-selected]="selection.isSelected(row.id)"> // add selected css class on check box checked.
</md-row>
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting ? can you recreate a plunker for same ? can you try the same with elementRef

Comment: Also it looks like you're overloading parameters to `onContextMenuClick`. Is that throwing an error?

Comment: Well thanks, It's working now. I've removed that param to only show the affected section.

Comment: If you solved it, you should post your own solution in answer... reads as having no answers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was angular change detector.
I've added remove class function inside of the check box selection function to clean up the previous css classes while checked, But angular detects changes and fire this function on each change so If i add css class when context click, it applied once on context click event but then it's removed from the checkbox function when angular detect change.

**inside the checkbox function i've added this line**

`$('md-row').removeClass('selected')`

**in the view**

```
<md-checkbox  color="primary"  
              (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" 
              (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row.id) : null" 
              [checked]="selection.isSelected(row.id)">
</md-checkbox>
```

The remove class fired each time of angular change detector runs, So my add class after context click applied at once then removed. I removed this line `$('md-row').removeClass('selected')` and refactored with this:

```
this.selection.onChange.takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$).subscribe(d => {
        if (this.selection.selected.length > 0) {
            // clean  onContext css classes.
            let elems = document.getElementsByTagName('md-row');
            for (let i = 0, len = elems.length; i < len; i++) {
                let classes = elems[i].classList;
                if (classes.contains('selected'))
                    classes.remove('selected');
        }  
     }
});
```